# How to use Angular forms with native FormData

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I'm working on an old project that uses the old way of submitting forms.
There is a `form` in the HTML that has the `method` and `action` defined.
I want to submit it the old way, by using the `action` of the form which should post the data that includes `form data` in the payload and refreshes the page (redirects) after submitting.

My issue is that it only works if you have regular `input` elements in the form. With regular inputs the `form data` will be populated automatically.
In my case I'm using custom components that are wrappers for the native inputs. This way I can still use reactive angular forms but my `form data` is empty when submitting.

I read that it is not possible to append additional form data fields to an existing HTML form.

Is there something I can do to manually (programatically) submit the form the same way that you would submit when you press on the button with `type = "submit"`. Only thing I can think of is to programatically create `input` elements, attach them to the actual HTML form, and trigger the form submit. But that seems really hacky.

EDIT:
`tl;dr` When you use custom elements that act as inputs, their values don't get attached to native `Form Data` (in the payload) when submitting a form. Is there anything I can do to either include those values in the `Form Data`, or to somehow manually make an `HTTP POST` call that actually reloads/renders that `HTML` that is in the response of the `POST` call?

Comment: When you import FormsModule / ReactiveForms it causes directives to be added to the form (selector `form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup])`) which does an `event.preventDefault()`. There is the `ngSubmit` output event and example in the docs https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Comment: Here is the link with example https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#listening-for-form-submission Otherwise please provide a small stackblitz

Comment: I don't really understand what I should do with the `ngSubmit` event, what I wanna do is post the form data and reload like it normally happens when you click on a submit button. How does the `ngSubmit` help exactly?

Comment: Sure I can build the `FormData` objet inside the onSubmit handler, and then manually POST that data, but that won't redirect me/render the HTML that is in the response of the Form action

Comment: You can not use `FormData` for a "normal" form submission - that is only usable in a context, where you want to make the request _using_ JavaScript. If you want your normal, run-of-the-mill form submission to submit extra data, that is not contained in actual form fields within the form already - then your only option is to dynamically _add_ (hidden) form fields and populate them with the values you want to send.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, that's what I was afraid of  I just don't understand why I can't do an HTTP POST request programatically that doesn't use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

"Old forms" simply do a POST request with form encoded URL body.

So do

```js
this.httpClient.post('myUrl', myform.value, { headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
} })
```

Comment: hmm when I do that the body `myform.value` is just included in the `Request Payload` inside the `Payload` tab, while it should be under `Form Data`. If I create an actual `FormData` object and send it instead of `myform.value` it's still in the `Request Payload` but with a weird structure. If I send the `FormData` but without these headers it all looks as it should, but does not reload

Comment: Using `x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content-type returns a `200 OK` status but does not re-render the page..

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked is programatically creating `<input>` elements with proper name/value and then submitting the form manually. Thanks @CBroe

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code.